# Do not render blank line where Django template tag is?

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to not render blank line where `django-tempte` tag is?

For instance the following template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Will render to such HTML:

```
## blank line here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Is there a way to make it render simply to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: why not using [django htmlmin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-htmlmin)?, anyway you also can using `{% spaceless %}` that you can found [here for more..](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `django-htmlmin`, perhaps this will be what I'm going to use in the end. `spaceless` is a tag by itself, hence it will leave blank line where it was specified, as there's nothing to minify anyway (you cannot minify more a single blank line which has been left from `load static`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give some more context as to why you need this? HTML is built so that spaces shouldn't matter. The space you're seeing is probably a newline character, not a space character. If you need to make it prettier, you can either put your Django tags on the same line as other HTML, e.g.

`<head>{% load static %}`

or use a minifier or other post-processor after Django renders the template.

The only possible exception to "spaces don't matter" is before your doctype declaration at the very beginning, which really needs to be the first line for the sake of browsers, web crawlers, and others who are looking for it there. If the code you posted is an actual excerpt, I would move your `{% load static %}` after your `<head>` tag because you won't need it until then anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the newline before your `<!DOCTYPE` it should do the trick:

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
```